# Prevent or skip rendering of symbols and entities Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have this function in my controller:

```
if ($request->get('query')) {
    $query = $request->get('query');

    $data = DB::table('users')
        ->where('is_archive', '=', 0)
        ->where(function($string) use ($query) {
            $string->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('church_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        })
        ->get();
}
```

What it does is a real-time search result that is listing same exact results as you type a letter. Same as the search bar of google that every time when you type a letter. it will show results that is the same as the currently typed text. I wish to put security features that will prevent the rendering of `<`, `>`, `'`, `"` etc. but it will accept space (spacebar) character. What I have done so far is:

```
$sanitizedQuery = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $query)));
```

but I seem to fail to achieve my desired outcome. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use  `{!! $var !!}` instead of `{{ $var }}`.

Comment: I see, will that provide me the rendering exception I need?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php